# Is my single flutter codebase can generate build in Android,iOS and webapps?

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, flutter-web, flutter-test

I have single codebase by using Android studio IDE with flutter SDK,

I am aware that flutter will give build for Android and iOS,
But I dont know Is flutter can give build for webapps (same codebase)?

Please help me with this concern.
Thank you

Comment: Check this: https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/codelab-web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, you need to enable the config for web

```
flutter channel beta
flutter upgrade
flutter config --enable-web
```

Make sure that the libraries you use are web compatible.  Checkout more at https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web